# Why isn't my 2x2 subfigure working?

Tags: graphics, subfig

I've googled and tried everything, I want 4 pictures to be in a 2x2 shape in a figure. I have used the following code

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/A_n100.jpeg}
         \caption[]{{\small $A$ full}}
         \label{fig:Afull}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/B_n100.jpeg}
         \caption[]{{\small $B$ full}}
         \label{fig:Bfull}
     \end{subfigure}
     \vskip\baselineskip
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/A_n100_zoomed.jpeg}
         \caption[]{{\small $A$ zoomed in}}
         \label{fig:Azoomed}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/B_n100_zoomed.jpeg}
         \caption[]{{\small $B$ zoomed in}}
         \label{fig:Bzoomed}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Tridiagonal shape of $A$ and $B$ for \texttt{n=100}}}
        \label{fig:aenb}
\end{figure}
```

and included the following packages

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

and it's just not showing up. What am i doing wrong? :(

Comment: used packages `subfig`, `\subfigure` (which is obsolete) and `subcaption` are not compatible. Use just last one ...

Comment: `\caption{Tridiagonal shape of $A$ and $B$ for \texttt{n=100}}}` has an additional brace `}`

Answer (score 2):

Let me spell out my comment:

- In your code fragment you have to much closed curly braces in main caption.
- Packages `subfig`, `\subfigure` (which is obsolete) and `subcaption` are not compatible. In your code fragment, you use only last one, so delete the other two.

Using `article` document class, a MWE (minimal Working Example) with your code fragment should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=small} if you like to change caption style
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/A_n100.jpeg}
         \caption[]{$A$ full} % <---
         \label{fig:Afull}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/B_n100.jpeg}
         \caption[]{$B$ full} % <---
         \label{fig:Bfull}
     \end{subfigure}

     \vskip\baselineskip
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/A_n100_zoomed.jpeg}
         \caption[]{$A$ zoomed in} % <---
         \label{fig:Azoomed}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/B_n100_zoomed.jpeg}
         \caption[]{$B$ zoomed in} % <---
         \label{fig:Bzoomed}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Tridiagonal shape of $A$ and $B$ for \texttt{n=100}} % <---
        \label{fig:aenb}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where are with `<---` marked places, where your code fragment is corrected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% ========== Packages ==========
\usepackage{graphicx, geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}




\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption[]{{\small $A$ full}}
        \label{fig:Afull}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption[]{{\small $B$ full}}
        \label{fig:Bfull}
    \end{subfigure}
\vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption[]{{\small $A$ zoomed in}}
        \label{fig:Azoomed}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption[]{{\small $B$ zoomed in}}
        \label{fig:Bzoomed}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Tridiagonal shape of $A$ and $B$ for \texttt{n=100}}
\label{fig:aenb}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: done the amendment here too

Comment: thanks, I deleted older comments